# TSQL query to retrieve flagged/total rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I'm struggling to find a solution to the following problem.
Assume, one has a table like this

```
 COL1 FLAG 
 aaa  1
 aaa  0
 aaa  1
 bbb  0
```

I need to write a query to get the following output:

```
COL1_VALUE FLAGGED TOTAL
aaa        2       3
bbb        0       1
```

where FLAGGED column contains the total count of the 'aaa' row values for which FLAG=1, and TOTAL column is the total number of rows containing 'aaa', in other words find how many rows containing 'aaa' are flagged in relation to total number of rows containing 'aaa'. Is it possible with a single query? (i.e. without using temp tables etc.)

(MSSQL2008)

Comment: It's called a "pivot" - there are lots of examples if you check the pivot tag.

Comment: What is the datatype of `FLAG`? Is it `bit`?

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT COL1 AS COL1_VALUE,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN FLAG = 1 THEN 1 END) AS FLAGGED,
       COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY COL1
```

Comment: Sorry, I have read "how many rows containing 'aaa' are flagged in relation to total number of rows containing 'aaa'." but not see expected results. YOu are right. +1

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT COL1, SUM(FLAG) AS FLAGGED, Count(*) AS TOTAL from tbl GROUP BY COL1
```

Comment: If `FLAG` is `BIT` this would need to be `SUM(CAST(FLAG AS INT))`

Comment: this is a nice solution either, without using CASE..WHEN. Thanks to Martin for this hint with CAST.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT    Tab.COL1 AS COL1_VALUE,
          SUM(CASE WHEN Tab.FLAG = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FLAGGED,
          COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM      Tab
GROUP BY  Tab.COL1
```

Comment: `COUNT(CASE WHEN Tab.FLAG = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FLAGGED` won't work. `COUNT` counts `NOT NULL` rows. Both branches of your `CASE` expression evaluate to `NOT NULL` so it is effectively the same as `COUNT(*)`

Comment: Should `COUNT(CASE WHEN Tab.FLAG = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` be `SUM(CASE WHEN Tab.FLAG = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`